# Selenium Webdriver tests are executed twice in Maven project

Tags: java, maven, selenium-webdriver

While executing the scipts through IntelliJ IDE, the tests are executed only once.

(Not sure is this because of the @Suite.SuiteClasses.) Please comment.

The details of the pom.xml are

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.selenium.webdriver</groupId>
  <artifactId>webdriver</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>webdriver</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.10</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
          <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
          <version>2.39.0</version>
      </dependency>
  </dependencies>
    <build>
    <plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0</version>
        <configuration>
            <source>1.7</source>
            <target>1.7</target>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.12.4</version>
    </plugin>
    </plugins>
    </build>
  </project>
```

Comment: Can you give the goals that phases selenium test? IE: test AND integration test

Comment: Hi farvilain, can you please elaborate your statement. Do you want me to write 'test AND integration test' against the Goal in Jenkins? Or should I create another tag <goal>test AND integration test</goal>?

Comment: I have a coworker that raged against the exact same problem. I remember it was due to SeleniumTest launched in test goal AND integration test goal, cause he didn't create exclusions like `exclude  *SeleniumTest` ... I will try to call him.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. The tests when executed via intellij either on terminal or by right click on the feature, ran the tests only once. But, the jenkins box was executing the tests twice. Did a 'Wipe Out Current Workspace' under workspace on the jenkins job and that had fixed the issue for me.